# My trusty kindle broke after many years and I never made a Kindle account, how can I transfer the books I have from the device to the kindle app?

Tags: amazon, kindle-app, send-to-kindle, kindle-fire

the screen of my Kindle broke a while ago and I thought I could just transfer the files of my Kindle device onto my Kindle account. I never bothered really setting up a Kindle account because I inherited my Kindle from my grandpa so I don't know his account login or anything of the sort. I am able to transfer some of the books using "Send to Kindle" that Amazon suggests but some of the book files are unsupported (these books were legitimately purchased very long ago but the files are APNX and not pdf). How can I resolve this? Or is fixing the screen the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the Kindle to a PC with a USB cable.  If no interactions are needed on the Kindle (i.e. selecting the type of USB connection), maybe the internal storage of the Kindle will then show up in a file manager.  Copy what you want from the kindle to PC storage.